# GetMessage id out of range from search scope

Tags: powershell, mailkit

I'm trying connect to IMAP-server using MailKit from powershell.
Connect to server, open inbox, search subfolders, select and open subfolder, query all messages (SeqrchQuery) and try get last message.
Example code:

```
'BouncyCastle.Crypto', 'mimekit', 'mailkit', 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options', 'cloudscribe.Messaging.Email' | %{Add-Type -Path "$(Join-Path 'D:\Mailkit' ($_ + '.dll'))"}
$mll = New-Object MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient
$ctoken = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken ($false)
$ssl = [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions]::Auto
$mll.Connect('server.name', 993, $ssl, $ctoken)
$mll.Authenticate(([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) , "user@server.name", "pass" , $ctoken)
$inbox = $mll.Inbox
$inbox.Open([MailKit.FolderAccess]::ReadOnly) | Out-Null
$inbox = $inbox.GetSubfolders($false) | ?{$_.Name -eq 'SUBFOLDER'}
$inbox.Open([MailKit.FolderAccess]::ReadOnly) | Out-Null
$src = $inbox.Search([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::All) 
$msg = $src | select -Last 1
try {$inbox.GetMessage($msg.Id)}
catch {
$_
}
$inbox.Close()
$mll.Disconnect($true , $ctoken)
Remove-Variable mll,inbox,msg,src,ctoken,ssl
```

And get error:

```
Exception calling "GetMessage" with "1" argument(s): "Argument value out of range.
Parameter name: index"
At line:23 char:1
+ $inbox.GetMessage($msg.Id)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: I try set off _\Seen_ flag to last received message, change search query to `$inbox.Search([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::NotSeen) | %{$inbox.GetMessage($_.id)}` and turn on builtin MailKit logging. And receive same error.
`S: * 476 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * OK [UNSEEN 476] First unseen.
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1415271545] UIDs valid
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 477] Predicted next UID
S: * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 4] Highest
S: L00000006 OK [READ-ONLY] Examine completed (0.001 secs).
C: L00000007 UID SEARCH RETURN () UNSEEN
S: * ESEARCH (TAG "L00000007") UID ALL 476`

Comment: Please don't add your solution to your question, post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: You cannot just subtract 1 to make it work. You are just getting lucky here. See my answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are hitting is that MailKit has 2 versions of `ImapFolder.GetMessage()`:

```
ImapFolder.GetMessage (int index)
ImapFolder.GetMessage (UniqueId uid)
```

The `Search()` method returns a list of `UniqueId` values. The `UniqueId` struct has a member called `Id` which is a `uint`.

When you pass `$msg.Id` to `GetMessage()`, it is invoking the `int` version of the API instead of the `UniqueId` version.

When it comes to IMAP, there's 2 ways of accessing messages. You can access them via their index or you can access them by their unique identifier.

Both of them look like integers, but they cannot be interchanged.

You need to use `$inbox.GetMessage ($msg)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But maybe possible convert between uid<>id?

Comment: I must define type of id, like `%{$id = [MailKit.UniqueId]($_.Id) ; $msg = $inbox.GetMessage($id)`

Comment: No, there’s no way to correctly convert between the 2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jstedfast for explain.
For correct working, I must define type of variable in method call.
Correct code:

```
$mll = New-Object MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient
$ctoken = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationToken ($false)
$ssl = [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions]::Auto
$mll.Connect('server.name', 993, $ssl, $ctoken)
$mll.Authenticate(([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) , "user@server.name", "pass" , $ctoken)
$inbox = $mll.Inbox
$inbox.Open([MailKit.FolderAccess]::ReadOnly) | Out-Null
$inbox = $inbox.GetSubfolders($false) | ?{$_.Name -eq 'SUBFOLDER'}
$inbox.Open([MailKit.FolderAccess]::ReadOnly) | Out-Null
$src = $inbox.Search([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::All) 
$msg = $src | select -Last 1
try { $id = [MailKit.UniqueId]($msg.Id) ; $inbox.GetMessage($id) }
catch { $_ }
$inbox.Close()
$mll.Disconnect($true , $ctoken)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should create a UID using your Uint value:

```
$UID = New-Object Mailkit.UniqueId(Msg.Id)
```

Then call your inbox.getMessage using the $UID instead of the msg.id

```
try {
  $inbox.GetMessage($UID)
} catch { 
  $_ 
}
```